# Name of type of video about many people saying short words to make a long speech

Tags: after-effects, final-cut-pro-x, adobe, final-cut-pro, transitions

Thanks for taking the time

Im looking for the name of type of video/transition where you have many clips from many people saying many words. So you can grab all of the (every word they pronounce) and make a long speech made from many shorts of every person saying 1 one word...

I remember one that was made time ago of Obama or Trump (or both)

*Im making a birthdate video card* :) =)

Comment: I've found jump cuts to be related, but after googling couldn't find much, under "jump cuts words"

Comment: Ok closer closer xD almost!!! I've found the Trump video, turns to be a "Mashup" [video-link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i4JxWkSYzU)